# Debian live build install doesn't find preseed.cfg file

Tags: debian

I'm trying to use Debian's live build tool to create a custom live .iso.    This is a first for me.  (I'm really just trying to come up with a standard image for an install on a bunch of PCs, so maybe I'm not using the right tool in the first place, but this is the path I've gone down.)

I have a custom list of packages that is included in the .iso, and that works fine.  I'm testing with VirtualBox.  But now I'm trying to avoid the manual bits of the install by specifying a preseed.cfg file, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.  I've tried putting it in config/preseed/ and config/includes.installer/, and I've also tried naming it config/preseed/preseed.cfg.chroot.  None seems to work.  Am I missing something obvious here...?  This should be doable, I assume?  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of fiddling around, what worked for me was putting preseed.cfg in config/includes.installer/.  I don't know why I didn't see this earlier.